# ODOO : is it a good practice to use administrator account in production

Tags: default, odoo, production-environment, administrator

I'm new in odoo world and I'm wondering if it's better to create a new account in order to use odoo, or just use the default admin account directly?

I do not like showing the admin in the contact list, so I would prefer to use the admin account directly by renaming it correctly with my personal information.

However, if it is better to use the administrator account just for installations and configurations tasks, I should use for hide admin account this module https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/10.0/hidden_admin/ or is there anyway a more integrated solution?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing inherently wrong with using the Administrator account in production as long as whoever is using that login can be trusted. I would recommend using the user's real Name and Email as login instead of Administrator and admin.

Another consideration is that some activities are programmed to be executed under administrator (usually via a `sudo` call somewhere in the code). This just means that there may be times where an action appears to have been done by the Administrator account, but it may have actually been triggered by a different user. I don't have a list of those actions, but you can search the codebase for `.sudo(` to review them for your situation.

```
grep -rn /path/to/core -e '\.sudo(' --include='*.py'
```

If that fails for some reason you can do a more generic search. The majority of these results will still be relevant.

```
grep -rn ./ -e 'sudo' --include='*.py'
```